# I keep getting false negatives when pinging my server in python

Tags: python, server, ping

I made some software to tell me when my server is down by pinging it every now and then, and then texting me with an att email that forwards to my phone number. but the issue is I keep getting false negatives and getting alerts when its working just fine and I don't know how to fix it this is my code. also is this the best approach to doing this?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def turnOn(GPIOPin):
    print("on")
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    GPIO.setup(GPIOPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(GPIOPin, GPIO.HIGH)

def turnOff(GPIOPin):
    print("off")
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    GPIO.setup(GPIOPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(GPIOPin, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()


try:
    turnOn(26)

    import platform    # For getting the operating system name
    import subprocess  # For executing a shell command

    '''
    Green LED: GPIO.17
    Red LED: GPIO.04
    White LED: GPIO.26
    '''
    import smtplib
    carriers = {
        'att':    '@mms.att.net',
        'tmobile':' @tmomail.net',
        'verizon':  '@vtext.com',
        'sprint':   '@page.nextel.com'
    }

    


    def send(message):
            # Replace the number with your own, or consider using an argument\dict for multiple people.
        to_number = 'phonenum{}'.format(carriers['att'])
        auth = ('', '')

        # Establish a secure session with gmail's outgoing SMTP server using your gmail account
        server = smtplib.SMTP( "mail.anonyomail.com", 587 )
        server.starttls()
        server.login(auth[0], auth[1])

        # Send text message through SMS gateway of destination number
        server.sendmail( auth[0], to_number, message)


    def ping(host):
        """
        Returns True if host (str) responds to a ping request.
        Remember that a host may not respond to a ping (ICMP) request even if the host name is valid.
        """

        # Option for the number of packets as a function of
        param = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'

        # Building the command. Ex: "ping -c 1 google.com"
        command = ['ping', param, '1', host]

        return subprocess.call(command) == 0

    import os
    from twilio.rest import Client

    if ping("anonyomail.com") == True:
        send("Anonyomail RasperryPI server is running")
        print("Sent text message telling CEO app is working")
        turnOn(17)

    import time
    i = 0
    e = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        if ping("anonyomail.com") == False:
            if i > 0:
                send("Anonyomail RasperryPI server is down!!!!")
            else:
                i += 1
            print("Sent text message telling CEO app is not working")
            turnOn(4)
        elif ping("anonyomail.com") == True:
            i = 0
            e = 0
            continue
        else:
            if e > 0:
                send("Something is wrong with the rasperrypi or the software monioring the status")
            else:
                e += 1
            print("Nah fam")
            turnOn(4)
finally:
    turnOff(26)
    turnOff(4)
    turnOff(17)
```

Comment: For troubleshooting I would ping the machine a few times inside your ping method and then see if any of them come back as True. pingResponse = [subprocess.call(command),subprocess.call(command),subprocess.call(command)]
    for attempt in pingResponse:
        if attempt == True:
            return (True)
            break
        return (False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed my issue I switched it from my domain name to my ip as well as doing some other things

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

time.sleep(30)

print("Server Status Monitor Version 1.1.1")
def turnOn(GPIOPin):
    print("on")
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    GPIO.setup(GPIOPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(GPIOPin, GPIO.HIGH)

def turnOff(GPIOPin):
    print("off")
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(GPIOPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(GPIOPin, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()


try:
    turnOn(26)

    import platform    # For getting the operating system name
    import subprocess  # For executing a shell command

    '''
    Green LED: GPIO.17
    Red LED: GPIO.04
    White LED: GPIO.26
    '''
    import smtplib
    carriers = {
        'att':    '@mms.att.net',
        'tmobile':' @tmomail.net',
        'verizon':  '@vtext.com',
        'sprint':   '@page.nextel.com'
    }

    


    def send(message):
            # Replace the number with your own, or consider using an argument\dict for multiple people.
        to_number = ''.format(carriers['att'])
        auth = ('', '')

        # Establish a secure session with gmail's outgoing SMTP server using your gmail account
        server = smtplib.SMTP( "mail.anonyomail.com", 587 )
        server.starttls()
        server.login(auth[0], auth[1])

        # Send text message through SMS gateway of destination number
        server.sendmail( auth[0], to_number, message)

    def sendEmail(message):
         # Replace the number with your own, or consider using an argument\dict for multiple people.
        to_number = ''
        auth = ('', '')

        # Establish a secure session with gmail's outgoing SMTP server using your gmail account
        server = smtplib.SMTP( "mail.anonyomail.com", 587 )
        server.starttls()
        server.login(auth[0], auth[1])

        # Send text message through SMS gateway of destination number
        server.sendmail( auth[0], to_number, message)

    def ping(host):
        """
        Returns True if host (str) responds to a ping request.
        Remember that a host may not respond to a ping (ICMP) request even if the host name is valid.
        """

        # Option for the number of packets as a function of
        param = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'

        # Building the command. Ex: "ping -c 1 google.com"
        command = ['ping', param, '1', host]

        return subprocess.call(command) == 0

    import os

    status = ping("192.168.1.199")

    if status == True:
        send("Anonyomail RasperryPI server is running")
        sendEmail("Anonyomail RasperryPI server is running")
        print("Sent text message telling CEO app is working")
        turnOn(17)

    import time
    i = 0
    e = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        status = ping("192.168.1.199")
        if status == False:
            if i > 0:
                send("Anonyomail RasperryPI server is down!!!!")
                sendEmail("Anonyomail RasperryPI server is down!!!!")               
            else:
                i += 1
            print("Sent text message telling CEO app is not working")
            turnOff(17)
            turnOn(4)
            turnOn(26)
        elif status == True:
            i = 0
            e = 0
            turnOff(4)
            turnOn(17)
            turnOn(26)
            continue
        else:
            if e > 0:
                send("Something is wrong with the rasperrypi or the software monioring the status")
                sendEmail("Something is wrong with the rasperrypi or the software monioring the status")               
            else:
                e += 1
            print("Nah fam")
            turnOn(4)
            turnOn(26)
            turnOff(17)

finally:
    turnOff(26)
    turnOff(4)
    turnOff(17)
```